Getting an error when I ran./scripts/cargo-install-all.sh . in macOS M3 terminal
Downloading Solana with this command:
git clone https://github.com/solana-labs/solana.git/
Finished cloning and going to enter the Solana directory and checkout the version branch v1.8.5:
cd solana
git checkout v1.8.5
Then ran this command:
./scripts/cargo-install-all.sh .
After running the command ./scripts/cargo-install-all.sh .
I get error: linking with cc failed: exit code: 1
|
= note: "cc" "-arch" "arm64" "-L" "/User...
I tried adding the following to ~/.cargo/config in VSCode:
[target.x86_64-apple-darwin]
rustflags = [
  "-C", "link-arg=-undefined",
  "-C", "link-arg=dynamic_lookup",
]

[target.aarch64-apple-darwin]
rustflags = [
  "-C", "link-arg=-undefined",
 "-C", "link-arg=dynamic_lookup",
]

Then, saved and closed. What is next?

From the short snippet of the error you've added all we can tell is that ther was an "error: linking with cc failed: exit code: 1 | = note: "cc" "-arch" "arm64" "-L" "/User…" the bit after that which contains actual information on why the linking failed and that we could use to help you is cut out.
Recheck if you have all dependencies installed properly and they can be found by your linker.

Thank you for your reply. I managed to resolve the linking issue. I got a new error when I ran the script again, which is:
(base) mtang@iMacM3 solana % ./scripts/cargo-install-all.sh .
Install location: /Users/mtang/solana (release)Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for the requirement ahash = "^0.6.1"
candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.4.8, 0.4.1, 0.4.0, ...
location searched: crates.io index
required by package solana-core v1.8.5 (/Users/mtang/solana/core)

Stack Overflow is not a forum which you seem to assume (as you're not posting a different question in a different post instead, you're trying to continue the thread here), so please add a [mre] including the complete error message to a new question if you decide to create one. The [tour] and [ask] are some resources that tell you about what SO is and how it works.

Noted. This is my first time posting here. Thanks for the suggestion. I appreciate it.  I will do better next time. I resolved all the issues, by the way.
